# Medieval synonym for outgun

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

[outgun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outgun): to surpass in firepower

Is there a similar word that could be applied in a story that avoids association with postmedieval weapons? A phrase would be acceptable but a single word would be preferred.

For example:

> With his opponent holding a sword Jim found himself `<outgunned>`<sup>1,2</sup>

<sub>1: Jim could be holding a knife, stick, or other puny weapon; so he isn't defenseless</sub>

<sub>2: Jim's opponent could be his twin brother equal in physical prowess; so he isn't outclassed</sub>

Comment: Do you want a term that was actually in Middle English, or do you merely want a term that avoids association with postmedieval weapons?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin I guess more the avoiding association with postmedieval weapons

Comment: I'm not an expert in ME but I would guess that they would have used a word with the sense of _overpower_. I've checked the historical thesaurus for _overpower_ in _OED_ and I've found the words _overswive_, _overgo_ and _outray_ that have the sense of _overpower/surpass_ and were used in ME. _OED_ doesn't have any historical words listed for _outgun_ or _outarm_ in the historical thesaurus.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/overwhelm

Comment: @HotLicks no one has beaten anyone yet, they are facing off one better armed than the other

Comment: _Outweapon_ came to my mind but it is from 1886 according to _OED_, even though the word _weapon_ was used in Middle English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several words in Middle English that would generally convey what you like, but they aren't limited to equippage or armaments, like *[outpass](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED31305)* and *[overweigh](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED32079)*. Other Middle English words might be adaptable to the situation, like *[feten](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED15819)*: one group may be *feted fairer* than the other, meaning that they have better equipment.

Since you aren't limited by that, I suggest **outarmed**. As defined by the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/133406):

> transitive. To possess a more powerful weapon than; to exceed in possession or acquisition of weapons of war. Also reflexive: to provide oneself with more arms than a competitor.
>
> 1866   Spectator 14 July 773/1   At the Bistritz, as at Nachod and Trautenau, the Austrians were outnumbered as well as outarmed.

Though its first usage is in the 19th century, the cognate verb *[arm](https://oed.com/view/Entry/10811)* would have been associated with weapons from the 13th century onward:

> a. transitive. To provide or supply (a person, army, ship, etc.) with weapons or military equipment in preparation for war or combat. Formerly also: †to provide (a knight, horse, etc.) with armour or mail (obsolete). Also reflexive.
>
> c1300   Life & Martyrdom Thomas Becket (Harl. 2277) (1845) 2113   This lithere Kniȝtes **armeden** hem eftsone.

Since **[out-](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED31171/track?counter=1&search_id=1903358)** is a recognized prefix in Middle English (see also *outpass*), **outarmed** would be a plausible hypothetical coinage for a historical novel. And of course it makes sense to modern audiences.

Answer (score 4):

I think **overmatched** would be reasonable:
[1 : to be more than a match for : defeat
2 : to match with a superior opponent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overmatch)

Comment: Or outmatched. .